# unable to clear text with in a progress circle

Tags: lightning-web-components, chartjs

I'm trying to build a progress ring using chart.js in lwc and here is my code.

HTML:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="bar" style={barstyle}>
            <svg>
              <circle cx='50%' cy='50%' r={circleradius}></circle>
            </svg>
            <h1 class="percentageVal slds-text-heading_medium" id="percentageVal">{percentageVal}</h1>
        </div>
    </div> 
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { api, LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import chartjs from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/chartjs';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
export default class D3progressRing extends LightningElement {
    isChartJsInitialized;
    chart;
    @api percentComplete;
    color;

    data;
    config;
    renderedCallback() {
        this.data = {
            labels: [
                "Red",
                "Blue"
            ],
            datasets: [
                {
                    data: [this.percentComplete, 100 - this.percentComplete],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        this.percentComplete >= 50 ? 'green' : 'red',
                        "lightgrey"
                    ]
                }]
        };
        this.config = {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: this.data,
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                segmentShowStroke: false,
                display: false,
                cutoutPercentage: 85

            }
        };
        if (this.isChartJsInitialized) {
            return;
        }
        this.isChartJsInitialized = true;

        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, chartjs)
        ]).then(() => {
            if (this.chart) {
                this.chart.destroy();
            }
            this.chart = new Chart(this.template.querySelector('canvas.linechart').getContext('2d'), this.config);
            var percent = null;

            var that = this;
            Chart.pluginService.register({
                beforeDraw: function (chart) {
                    var width = chart.chart.width,
                        height = chart.chart.height,
                        ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
                    
                    ctx.restore();
                    var fontSize = (height / 114).toFixed(2);
                    ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
                    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
                    const text = `${that.percentComplete}%`,
                        textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
                        textY = height / 2;

                    ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
                    ctx.save();
                }
            });
        }).catch(error => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error loading ChartJS',
                    message: error.message,
                    variant: 'error',
                }),
            );
        });
    }
}
```

when I drag and drop this component into my record page, there are 2 issues that I'm facing.

1. When I change the value from the design attribute, the chart gets re-rendered correctly, but the content within the circle (`that.percentComplete`) is getting overlapped with the previous value instead of deleting it.
2. when I have this component in multiple places on the same page, then also I see the overlap happening, and strangely, it is taking content from another chart placed on the same page.

Please let me know where am I going wrong and how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: pointing out a typo in your post code (dont know about your actual setup) =>
`that.percentComplete` => `this.percentComplete`

Comment: @glls `that = this`, they're trying to preserve `this`.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, when I don't use that and use `this.percentComplete`, it doesn't show anything

Comment: Hi @glls, I made that as part of my code as I don't see any text printing if I use `this.percentComplete`

Answer (score 1):

You're restoring the previous content, then drawing on top of it. This appears to be what's creating the problem of the overlapping data. Remove this line:

```
// ctx.restore();
```

Alternatively, consider using `afterDraw` so you can draw on top of the chart.